# how to compare drop down index

Tags: c#, asp.net

i need to compare five drop down list index. it should not be same except zero index

aspx page code same for all five drop down list

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList_l1_5" runat="server" 
                    OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList_l1_5_SelectedIndexChanged" 
                    AutoPostBack="True">
                    <asp:ListItem>Select</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="1">Neck</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="2">Shoulder</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="3">Arm</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="4">Lower Back</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="5">Leg</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="6">Other</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList>
```

i tried below code

```
    int idx1 = DropDownList_l1_1.SelectedIndex;
    int idx2 = DropDownList_l1_2.SelectedIndex;
    int idx3 = DropDownList_l1_3.SelectedIndex;
    int idx4 = DropDownList_l1_4.SelectedIndex;
    int idx5 = DropDownList_l1_5.SelectedIndex;

    if (idx1 != 0 || idx2 != 0 || idx3 != 0 || idx4 != 0 || idx5 != 0)//this line is probelm
        if (idx1 != idx2 || idx1 != idx3 || idx1 != idx4 || idx1 != idx5)
        {
          // statement
        }
```

any idea....

Comment: do you need all 5 index should not be same or none of the two should be same

Comment: What do you mean *compare five drop down list index*?

Comment: The if statement is true when at least one of the indexes is not 0. What would you exactly want?

Comment: You need to use `&&` if you want your first condition to check if all dropdowns have been selected

Comment: i need all 5 index should not be same except zero index(select)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's kinda tough to say exactly what you're trying to do. I *think* you're saying that:

- it's okay if one or more drop down lists have no selection (SelectedIndex = 0)
- if one or more drop down lists actually *has* a selection, then none of them can share the same `SelectedIndex` value

If that's the case, then you could use a simple LINQ statement like the following. It ignores values of 0 *(no selection in the list)*, then makes sure that each index value *(1, 2, etc)* only occurs once.

```
var allIndexes = new List<int>
{
    DropDownList_l1_1.SelectedIndex,
    DropDownList_l1_2.SelectedIndex,
    DropDownList_l1_3.SelectedIndex,
    DropDownList_l1_4.SelectedIndex,
    DropDownList_l1_5.SelectedIndex
};

var noSelectedIndexIsTheSame = allIndexes.Where(x => x != 0)
                                         .GroupBy(x => x)
                                         .All(x => x.Count() == 1);

if (noSelectedIndexIsTheSame)
{
   // no selected values are the same, so do something
   ...
}
```

Comment: if i need to do some thing in selected index zero code is if (noSelectedIndexIsTheSame)
{
   // no selected values are the same, so do something
   ...
}else{ //zero index  }????

Comment: thanks for expatiation

Comment: error is if i select any index its return true. var SelectedIndexIsTheSame_0 = allIndexes.Any(x => x == 0);

Answer (score 2):

The condition should be check with `&&` in stead of `||`

```
if(idx1 != 0 && idx2 != 0 && idx3 != 0 && idx4 != 0 && idx5 != 0)
    if( idx1 != idx2 && idx1 != idx3 && idx1 != idx4 && idx1 != idx5 )
    {
        //Statement     
    }
```

UPDATED:

```
if(idx1 != 0 && idx2 != 0 && idx3 != 0 && idx4 != 0 && idx5 != 0)
    if( idx1 != idx2 && idx1 != idx3 && idx1 != idx4 && idx1 != idx5 && 
                        idx2 != idx3 && idx2 != idx4 && idx2 != idx5 && 
                                        idx3 != idx4 && idx3 != idx5 && 
                                                        idx4 != idx5 
    )
    {
        // statement
    }
```

Comment: It depends when you want //statement to execute. This is still not clear in OP's question

Comment: ah, yes, OP's question is not clear yet.  
i guess, OP wants to check for 5 different choices. 
the code is still needed to change second `if` statement.

Answer (score 0):

The big issue here is the fact you are using the wrong UI metaphor to select things. You have 5 items in a list, you have 5 drop downs, you want to select each item a maximum of once. This is also very difficult to work with for the programmer.

How can we determine if a Neck was chosen?

```
if (idx1 == 1
  || idx2 == 1  
  || idx3 == 1
  || idx4 == 1
  || idx5 == 1) //neck chosen
```

Wouldn't this be better as a set of checkboxes

```
[x] Neck
[ ] Shoulders
[ ] Arm
[ ] Lower back
[ ] Leg
```

Now the user can only select each item once, and the programmer has only one place to check if the neck is chosen.

```
if (chkNeck.IsChecked) //neck chosen
```